# Limit of an indicator martingale

Tags: convergence-divergence, martingales

Consider the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.
We define $I_k^n=[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})$, for $0\leq k\leq 2^n-1$, and $F_n=\sigma(\{I^n_k:k\})$.
Finally $M_n=1_{I_0^n}2^n$.

> How do we show that $M_n$ is a martingale? And what is its limit $M$?

For martingale we must show
$$\mathbb{E}[1_{I_0^n}2^n|F_{n-1}]=1_{I_0^{n-1}}2^{n-1}.$$
I know that $I_0^{n-1}=I_0^{n}\sqcup I_1^n$, but how does one then show the identity?

Further I have a feeling that $M=0$ since $I_0^n\to\{0\}$, but again, how is this shown?

Comment: The first part is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/919324/36150). For the limit $M$ we have $M=\lim_{n \to \infty}  2^n 1_{I_0^n}=0$ almost surely; this follows from the fact that for any $\omega \in (0,1]$ there exists $N=N(\omega)$ sufficiently large such that $\omega \notin I_0^n$ for all $n \geq N$, i.e. $1_{I_0^n}(\omega)=0$ for all $n \geq N$.